# NStepLSTM and Seq2Seq model

Tags: python, chainer

Dear chainer community,

I can't struggle the logic usage of `NStepLSTM` in `seq2seq` [official example](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/tree/master/examples/seq2seq) (English to French translation).

1. `def __call__(self, xs, ys):
       xs = [x[::-1] for x in xs] #Reverse x` as far as I can understand `xs` is a English phrase and `ys` is a French phrase. Why do you reverse the English phrase?
2. How do you train the network? You embed `xs` and `ys` into continuous space and then feed the encoder with `exs` to obtain a latent representation of the English phrase. But then you put the latent representation into decoder with `eys`. But `eys` is a continuos representation of the French phrase, On the test stage decoder can't know the resulting French phrase, can it? How can you apply your network?

   `hx, cx, _ = self.the encoder(None, None, exs)
   _, _, os = self.decoder(hx, cx, eys)`
3. `ys_in = [F.concat([eos, y], axis=0) for y in ys]` why we put `end of sequence` at the beginning?
4. `ys = self.xp.full(batch, EOS, 'i')` in `def translate` , we put array of `end of sequence` to decoder, why?

What should I do if I don't want to translate sentences but to build an autoencoder for mapping phrases into the latent space?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

> Question 1

Please see following seq2seq original paper. 
They suggest that:

`Note that the LSTM reads the input sentence in reverse, because doing so introduces many short term dependencies in the data that make the optimization problem much easier.`

(In Abstract)

`we found that reversing the order of the words in all source sentences (but
not target sentences) improved the LSTM’s performance markedly`

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf

I think the official example code also reverses the input sentence as above paper.

> Question 2
>
> > But then you put the latent representation into decoder with `eys`. But `eys` is a continuos representation of the French phrase

Yes.This code is used in training time, so we know target sentence (gold words).

```
hx, cx, _ = self.the encoder(None, None, exs)
_, _, os = self.decoder(hx, cx, eys)
```

At test time, you should use `def translate(self, xs, max_length=100):`.
This method can be used to predict sentence from source sentence `xs`.

```
result = []
for i in range(max_length):
    eys = self.embed_y(ys)
    eys = F.split_axis(eys, batch, 0)
    h, c, ys = self.decoder(h, c, eys)
    cys = F.concat(ys, axis=0)
    wy = self.W(cys)
    ys = self.xp.argmax(wy.data, axis=1).astype('i')
    result.append(ys)
```

For each loop, predict a word with source sentence vector and a previous word `ys`.

> Question 3
>   Question 4

I think this part should be as following:
`ys_in = [F.concat([bos, y], axis=0) for y in ys]` (begin of sentence)
The official code use `eos` for both  and .

> Final Question
>
> What should I do if I don't want to translate sentences but to build an autoencoder for mapping phrases into the latent space?

When you want to build an autoencoder,

1. remove this line `xs = [x[::-1] for x in xs]`
2. use `bos` instead of `eos` in `ys_in = [F.concat([eos, y], axis=0) for y in ys]`

Both are fine whether use `eos` instead of `bos`.
You just remove this line `xs = [x[::-1] for x in xs]` for an autoencoder.

If you want to use `bos`, you should modify like following:

```
UNK = 0
EOS = 1
BOS = 2



47:eos = self.xp.array([EOS], 'i')
48: ys_in = [F.concat([eos, y], axis=0) for y in ys]
=>
bos = self.xp.array([BOS], 'i')
ys_in = [F.concat([bos, y], axis=0) for y in ys]
79: ys = self.xp.full(batch, EOS, 'i')
=> 
ys = self.xp.full(batch, BOS, 'i')

def load_vocabulary(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        # +2 for UNK and EOS
        word_ids = {line.strip(): i + 3 for i, line in enumerate(f)}
    word_ids['<UNK>'] = 0
    word_ids['<EOS>'] = 1
    word_ids['<BOS>'] = 2
    return word_ids
```

If you have further question, please ask me again.